# How to create a file in a folder in java

Tags: java, file

I have created a file named `Student`, however I would like to create a folder called `School` and make a file called `Student` inside that folder  how can I do it?

My code below:

```
public void upload() throws IOException {
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("student.txt");
        BufferedWriter buffer = new BufferedWriter(writer);
        buffer.write(generatedText);
        buffer.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `mkdir()` method from File class:

```
new File("path\\School").mkdir();
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("path\\School\\student.txt");
BufferedWriter buffer = new BufferedWriter(writer);
buffer.write("Hello");
buffer.close();
```

Here `path` need to be replaced with your system path for the .

Comment: `File.pathSeparator()` is the by-the-book approach.